# Rails "Unpermitted parameters" error even though the attributes are permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby On Rails 5 and have 2 tables:

1) Table Archives with columns shelfmark, harddisk_id

2) Table Harddisks with columns label, capacity

I have an archive form that looks like this (app/views/archives/_form.html.erb)

```
<%= form_with(model: archive, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :shelfmark %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :shelfmark %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :harddisk do |harddisk_fields| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= harddisk_fields.label "Harddisk capacity" %><br />
      <%= harddisk_fields.text_field :capacity %><br />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label "Harddisk Label" %><br />
      <%= form.select :harddisk_id, Harddisk.order(label: :asc).collect {|a| [ a.label, a.id ] } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in archives_controller.rb default CRUD methods with following snippet:

```
  def archive_params
    params.require(:archive)
          .permit(:id, :shelfmark, :harddisk_id, harddisk_attributes: [:id, :capacity, :label])
  end
```

When I select a harddisk label from dropdown and click on save, I get an "success" message but the harddisk label field is not updated.

On Rails server console I can see the message:

> "Unpermitted parameters: :harddisk_attributes, :harddisk_id"

I did permit these attributes already in archives_controller or do I have to permit it elsewhere, too?
What am I missing?

---

in app/controllers/archives_controller.rb:

```
def edit
end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @archive.update(archive_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @archive, notice: 'Archive entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @archive }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @archive.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails server log:

```
Started PATCH "/archives/1" for ::1 at 2018-02-08 15:44:09 +0100
Processing by ImagecapturingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TfThFrCaA34qi3YliuGVliaaifCBk2KxRXlvA0UMEM2evFUe7M8ODwY5U/FEimNz+NXqdqr+HSKbU6sLRoSVBw==", "archive"=>{"shelfmark"=>"csg-0070 foo", "harddisk_attributes"=>{"capacity"=>"932", "id"=>"1"}, "harddisk_id"=>"135"}, "commit"=>"Update Archive", "id"=>"1"}
  Archive Load (31.4ms)  SELECT  `archive`.* FROM `archive` WHERE `archive`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: :harddisk_attributes, :harddisk_id
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Harddisk Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `harddisks`.* FROM `harddisks` WHERE `harddisks`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/archives/1
Completed 302 Found in 86ms (ActiveRecord: 33.0ms)
```

and my models:

```
class Archive < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :harddisk
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :harddisk
end

class Harddisk < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :manuscripts, through: :manuscripts_harddisks
end
```

---

does this snippet from the server log:

```
"archive"=>{
"shelfmark"=>"csg-0070 foo", "harddisk_attributes"=>{"capacity"=>"932", "id"=>"1"}, "harddisk_id"=>"135"}, "commit"=>"Update Archive", "id"=>"1"}
```

indicates that the translation from harddisk_id: 135 and id:1 went wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code for your controller method, and also a (sanitized) sample of the `params` from the rails server console?

Comment: Also, can you share archive and harddisk model relations?

Comment: see updated post.

Comment: There is no relation from Harddisk model to Archive model.

Comment: regarding the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association by using belongs_to one doesn't need a relation from Harddisk to Archive model - a belongs_to in Archive model should be enough-, or not?

Comment: Looking at your log I see that the action is actually ImageCapturingsController#update so maybe you are debugging in wrong controller? Permit the neccessary attributes in image_capturings_controller#update and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Andres, yes, you're right! The Archive model is inherited from ImageCapturing model but I have separate controller. the submit button triggers for some reason the imagecapturing controller method. How can I force that the submit button triggers the method in archives_controller instead of imagecapturings_controller?

Comment: If you need different action to trigger then you could specify url in the outer `form_with` tag. Something like `form_with(model: archive, local: true, url: archive_action_path)`

Comment: when I use <%= form_with(model: archive, local: true, url: edit_archives_path) do |form| %> I get No route matches [PATCH] "/archives/1/edit even though I have archives resource in routes.rb

Comment: What does `rake routes` give for archives#edit action? I assume if you have inheritance used (archive inherits from image_capturing) then you might need to create some custom routes.

Comment: edit_archive GET    /archives/:id/edit(.:format)                      archives#edit